# Calculate Image Loading time in PHP

Tags: php, image, image-processing

I have a PHP script that retrieve an image from a GET variable, processing and crop the image.
I need to know how many seconds it takes not only for process, but also for render and see the image on his browser.

My script below:

```
<?php
$start_time = explode(' ', microtime())[0] + explode(' ', microtime())[1];
// process image bla bla bla
$end_time = round((explode(' ', microtime())[0] + explode(' ', microtime())[1]) - $start, 4);
?>
```

only calculate the time of script processing.

How can I know server side the complete time of both processing and render/view/download on browser?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can't detect that info with a server-side language like PHP. Javascript can fire events when the image has loaded, though - why don't you look into that?

Comment: FYI, if you pass a truthy value to `microtime()` you'll get back a float instead of a string and you don't have to parse it.

Comment: All of those you mention means measuring http response time, which you can easily find out using your browser developer tools.

Comment: @revo I have to storage into database this response time, so i need to got it dinamically.

Comment: Then there is no way using PHP. You may use calculate time of PHP process at the end of output buffer, send it to browser, then using JS to add page loading time to PHP time then send it back to server.